# How to use settings to show / hide content in your view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 5 application I have an item card with a partial view. Based on a setting (stored in my settings table) I want to show / hide specific columns).

Settings table:

- Id = 1 | Group = ItemCard   | Key = ShowStockValue | Value = 0
- Id = 2 | Group = OtherGroup | Key = SomeKey     | Value = SomeValue
- etc.

**StockViewModel**

```
public class StockViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string StockValue { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller (partial view action):**

```
public PartialViewResult PartialViewItemStock(int? id)
{
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    ItemStockRepository itemStockRepo = new ItemStockRepository();
    WarehouseRepository warehouseRepo = new WarehouseRepository();

    var warehouses = warehouseRepo.GetWarehousesPerItemId(id.Value);

    var stock = itemStockRepo.GetStockPositionsPerWarehouse(id.Value, warehouses, currentDate).ToList();

    return PartialView("_PartialViewItemStock", stock);
}
```

In my View I want to hide the column `StockValue` based on the setting `ShowStockValue`. I was thinking to put something like this in my partial view action:

```
ViewBag.CardSettings = settingsRepo.GetSettingsByGroup("ItemGroup");
```

And in my view loop through the settings

or directly put the setting in the ViewBag like `ViewBag.ShowStockValue`

but I don't know if this is the way to go?

Comment: If you want to hide a column then its better to use ViewBag.ShowStockValue.